# ckeditor4 filebrowser upload url: url params are not added

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I upgraded to CKeditor4 from version 3. Sadly my file and image upload integration does not work anymore.

CKeditor should add some url params as described here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html

> CKEditor automatically sends some additional arguments to the file
>   manager: CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

That doesn't happen with version 4.

Here is a fiddle with instructions to reproduce:
https://jsfiddle.net/5wzh9a08/1/

```
<html lang="de">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>
CKeditor 4 upload problem
</h1>

<p>
Problem: CKeditor 4 does not append "CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" to the upload URL.
</p>
<p>
How to reproduce:
</p>
<ul>
<li>Open web developer console in browser</li>
<li>Click (and enable) network tab</li>
<li>In CKeditor: click on image icon</li>
<li>Click "upload", select a file and click "Send to server"</li>
<li>Watch the request in web developer console: the necessary url params are not added.</li>
</ul>
<p>
Reference: <a href="https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html">https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html</a>
</p>

<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="8" cols="80">
  test 123
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/upload.html',
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

CKEditor4 needs the option

```
config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';
```